# Configure SSRS Report Data Source Link programmatically via PowerShell or Console Application

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, reporting-services

I require to set the data source link of SSRS reports.

The SSRS Reports and the Data Source reside in a document library. I want to set the shared data source for all the SSRS reports of the document library.

I tried to achieve it using PowerShell and by consuming the SSRS Report Service in a console application. But in both the approaches, I faced below issues:

1. Getting the Data Source associated with an SSRS report using ***GetItemDataSources***:

> Exception calling "GetItemDataSources" with "1" argument(s): "Report
>   Server has encountered a SharePoint error. --->
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.SharePointException:
>   Report Server has encountered a SharePoint error. --->
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The user does not exist or is not
>   unique.

2. While reading the contents of the root folder of the ***SSRS report*** document library which contains all SSRS reports using ***ListChildren***:

> Exception calling "ListChildren" with "2" argument(s): "The
>   permissions granted to user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' are
>   insufficient for performing this operation. --->
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.AccessDeniedException:
>   The permissions granted to user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' are
>   insufficient for performing this operation."

Any help will be grateful!!!